# What are the odds of a at least a certain amount of aces being dealt depending on the number of players?

Tags: odds, probability

I'm interested to know what the odds are of at least a certain amount of aces being dealt anywhere, depending on the amount of players.

```
             Zero Aces | At least 1 Ace | At least 2 Aces | At least 3 Aces | 4 Aces
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10 Players |           |                |                 |                 |
 9 Players |           |                |                 |                 |
 8 Players |           |                |                 |                 |
 7 Players |           |                |                 |                 |
 6 Players |           |                |                 |                 |
 5 Players |           |                |                 |                 |
 4 Players |           |                |                 |                 |
 3 Players |           |                |                 |                 |
 2 Players |           |                |                 |                 |
```

I'd like to expand on why I'm interested in knowing this. I'm trying to explain to friends of mine who are starting to play poker that the likelihood of facing an Ace is something to take into account, but is dependent on how many players are on the table.

I was told that when playing ten handed, the likelihood of facing at least one Ace is quite high. (90% or so) So, I'm interested in the exact numbers so I have something to talk about.

Comment: Interested to know why this is important to you?  Single ace in two hands is way different than two aces in one hand.   If you have a pair of kings and there is an ace on the board you are beat by any ace - does it matter if three hands can beat you.

Comment: Curiosity. How often do we have to deal with others having an Ace. Say I have KK, when in a ten handed game, what are the odds of someone having an Ace?

Comment: Then why are you asking for the chances of 2,3,4 aces being out?

Comment: Same story more or less. When holding Ax, what are the odds I'm facing someone with Ax as well.

Comment: There's 52 cards, 4 of them are aces. It's approximately a 8% chance that any specific card is an ace. What more do you really care about?

Comment: Seems you people are unwilling to answer my question. Do I need to make a case my question is important to me? Really strange. This is not how I remember StackExchange.

Comment: I guess rarely anyone care, if no one cares there's a good chance it's not an important factor of the game. I don't care if someone has an ace if I got kings, the only thing that matters is if someone will match their ace. Here might be some statistics relevant to your case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability_(Texas_hold_%27em)

Comment: I do care if I have kings and I see the board showing an Ace. Thanks for the link! I'll check it out.

Comment: Being cautious when you have Kings and the board has an Ace is prudent - you suddenly have a much smaller hand than you started with. Knowing the odds of someone else having an ace in that situation isn't too relevant; what is relevant is the odds of them betting their ace vs. betting junk, and this has little to do with their odds of having the ace in the first place. After all, the odds of them having one ace is equal to the odds of each of the people that folded having folded an ace.

Comment: It isn't that we don't care it's just that the question and answer are not very relevant and answering the question sends the wrong message to more novice players.  If you have kings and the flop comes down A56 are you all of the sudden not going to make a Cbet?  Or are you only going to make a Cbet 8% of the time?  8% is pretty low, if a tight player called you are you going to Cbet him 82% of the time?  Once the flop comes down, the chances of anyone holding an ace is meaningless.  Once the flop drops, the most important information is how they played pre-flop and their hand ranges.

Comment: Isn't it statistically interesting to be aware of the fact that someone else holding an ace is quite common? It's the classic story of novice players falling in love with their K or Q, not taking into account that any ace would probably have them beat?

Comment: Not to me it isn't.  Because if I am playing kings correctly, the only people likely to call my bet or reraise me either have a high pocket pair or Ax.  So if an ace comes down, there is a decent chance someone is holding one.  And I would say that number is higher than any math of these statistics would give you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the chances (assuming you have no ace):

[image]

These are valid only preflop assuming that there are 50 cards left in the deck (you are holding 2) and you are one of the players (2 players = 1 opponent with 2 cards; 3 players = 2 opponents with 4 cards and so on)

Comment: I don't think this is quite right...I'd be interested in seeing how you did it.  For the 2players-0aces, this should simply be (46/50)(45/49)(44/48)(43/47) = .709 which doesn't match your .828.  Also, on the 10 players line, I see that you have the odds of 4 aces being dealt as higher than the odds of zero aces being dealt, but just intuitively it seems like that inequality should be go the opposite way since less than half the deck is being dealt out.

Comment: I finally tried out doing this whole table for myself and mine matches your exactly in the 0-aces, at-least-1-ace, and 4-aces columns but does not for the other two columns, especially as the number of players goes up.  The thing that looks fishy now is that for the 10-players row, it's implied that there's only a 9% chance of there being exactly one ace, but 58% chance of there being exactly two?  FYI, I tried it in Excel with the HYPEGEOMDIST function.

Comment: Third time's the charm :)

Comment: Well done, sir.

Comment: Can you show your calcs?

Comment: eg. 5 players = 8 cards delt. You care about number of card combinations - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination
0 aces - possible combinations with no ace - (46!/((46-8)!*8!)) divided by the total possible combinations - (50!/((50-8)!*8!))

exactly 1 ace - combinations of chosing 1 ace = 4 multiplied by the combinations of choosing the other 7: 46!/((46-7)!*7!) divided by the total number of combinations(same as for 0)
exactly 2 aces - (combos of choosing 2 aces = 6) x (46!/((46-6)!*6!)) / total:(50!/((50-8)!*8!))
exactly 3 aces - 4 x (46!/((46-5)!*5!)) / total

Comment: To calculate at least 2 aces you sum (exactly4 + exactly3 + exactly2)

Comment: Thanks! This thread has kept me from getting a good night's sleep ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't go by strictly odds, because the odds are good that an ace was not folded preflop.

My assumption, on a full table (8-10) is there are 2 aces in the pockets; I'll confirm more exactly, & who has them once we start doing post-flop betting.

I read this on another site & found it valid/useful, for the raw odds for 2 of you having aces(relevant to assessing your kicker, if you're one of them)

> Depends on how many people are at the table originally, I think one of the things that doesn't get communicated properly is the filtering effect.

In micro, alot of people play an A no matter what its paired with if you want to assume that is true in a 9 way then your really asking what is the probability that any of my other 8 opponents were dealt an ace preflop even if there is only one left post flop. This is easiest calculated as the probability that none of the 8 people hit an ace. To do this we just imagine dealing out 16 cards out of a 47 card deck with 2 aces left in it.

The probability of not dealing an ace on the first card is 45/47. The probability of not dealing an ace on the second card is 44/46. On down to 30/32.

Multiplying all these together gives a bunch of fractiosn most of the terms can be canceled and you get 31*30 / (47*46) = .43.

So the probability one of the other 16 cards is an ace given what you flopped is .57. And you have to figure they would limp in wiht it at 1bb or if they are loose play it at 3bb at a low stakes table. So even if you are down to one person you have to put him on it 57% of the time.

Now your not supposed to play an ace with a weak kicker on a big table, and incidentally this is exactly why. 57% of the time some one else has it, but if your kicker is weak more than not they got you dominated.

Don't fall in love with AT or A9, because the odds are good that another retained ace hasa better kicker; now, if you flop top pair, though, you're in good shape for thefirst post-flop betting round, but you've got a less than 5% chance of doing that -- of course, it's called gambling for a reason -- I tend to play a 9 or higher kicker to my ace, especially if suited(only less than a 1% chance of flopping a flush, but, hey, if I hit, or even get a 4-flush on the flop, I'm happy to push the pot up for a later payoff(look up "implied odds" & "pot odds")

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why no one has answered this for you yet. It's a reasonable thing to want to know, but as others may have mentioned, should be more for novelty than for using to make your in-game decisions.

Anyways, here's a breakdown I put together. A lot of figures are fractions of percents, so I simplified it by rounding everything up to the nearest whole percent.

The likelihood of an Ace is always the same, what changes is the number of cards in play based on the number of players. The more players, the more cards dealt, meaning the more likely there is someone has at least one Ace. I made two charts; the first one is for 2-10 players in general, and the second is an adjusted chart which assumes that you are one of the players, and you have two non-Ace cards. This means there are effectively only 50 cards in the deck, instead of 52. These figures are, of course, based on pre-flop distribution.

[image]

[image]

**The likelihood changes based on how many Aces are in play.**
1st Ace = 1/13 (4/52)
2nd Ace = 1/17 (3/51)
3rd Ace = 1/25 (2/50)
4th Ace = 1/49 (1/49)

Hopefully this is what you were looking for!

Comment: I think your math is off.  #1 you can't have more than 100% chance when it comes to probability.  And #2 there is no way 8 out 100 hands 4 aces are dealt.  It's more like 8 out of 100 hands in a hand with 2 players one of the 4 cards would be an ace.

Comment: It's possible I have done this wrong. I agree about not going over 100%, I should have double-checked that. This table is based on an auto-formula I made in Excel, calculating cards dealt/single-card probability. So if the odds of a single Ace is 1/13 (4 out of 52 cards), then with 7 players (14 cards dealt), I put 14/13.

It does seem strange to me as well though, that these percentages are so high. Hmm, I wonder what I did wrong, then.

Comment: Good attempt, I like the format and all but your approach is off. If you're not familiar with combinatorics, I'd suggest learning about it as it's how I would go about this. For example, the case of 2 aces being dealt to 4 players would amount to considering the total number of 8 card possibilities that can be dealt from a deck [52 choose 8] and divide into that the product of [48 choose 6] --(i.e. number of ways that 6 non-aces can be chosen)--and [4 choose 2] --(i.e. number of ways that the 2 aces can be chosen from the 4 total aces).  The answer should be 9.8%

Comment: One thing I should have mentioned is that when I calculated the odds of subsequent Aces (2nd, 3rd, 4th), it is supposed to be the odds of that Ace coming assuming the other Ace(s) are already dealt. 

So, for the 2-Players 2nd Ace (24%), this % is the remaining Aces/the remaining cards (not including the first Ace). If there are 52 cards, 4 of which are Aces, the odds for the first Ace are 4/52, which becomes 1/13 or 7.69% (which I rounded up to 8%). After that first Ace has been dealt, the odds for a second now become 3/51, which becomes 1/17 or 5.88% (which I rounded up to 6%). And so on.

Comment: I did not vote you down but no way that is correct.  Two player both get aces 8%?   The chance of you getting aces is just 0.45%

Comment: Yeah I didn't vote down either.  I love the format, just work on the calculations some. :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, guys. I wasn't 154% sure my math was correct, but now I'm getting at least some direction on where I went wrong. Thanks also, Dr. Drfbaglll, I am looking more into combinatorics. :)